# Error in model.frame.default variable lengths differ

Tags: r, glm

Here I get the **90%** of the **Boston dataset** as the **training set**, and **10%** as the **testing set**. So here there are **400** rows of the **training set**, 106 rows of the **testing set**, and 506 rows for the **Crime set** and all these variables in **Boston set**. So when I tried to do the logistic fit, I got the following error

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = Crime ~ zn + indus) variable lengths differ

I have no idea of how to fix that because it seems that the length of **training set** should always be **less than** the length of its **parent dataset Boston**. Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

```
library(MASS)
med = median(Boston$crim)
set =  sample(seq(1,2),size=nrow(Boston),replace = TRUE,prob=c(.9,.1))
train = Boston[set == 1,]
test = Boston[set == 2,]
Crime = as.numeric(Boston$crim > med)
attach(Boston)
logistic.fit = glm(Crime~zn+indus,data=train,family=binomial)
```

[The description of train, test and Boston](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTK7K.png)

Comment: Can you add code where `med` is defined so that this example is reproducible?

Comment: Sure,I added that

Comment: You're using dataset `train` but your response `Crime` is based on the full (and larger) dataset `Boston`. So `Crime = as.numeric(train$crim > med)` should fix the problem.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right! But I was just wondering that if that would have negative influence on the model? If I only take the train set part to build this model?

Comment: I *am* right;-) You're splitting your data into a training and test set. So obviously you train your model on the training set. Then independently assess your model using the test set. Why else would you split your data...?

Comment: Perhaps there is a confusion on what test and training data are and why to use them? For more information see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Training,_test,_and_validation_sets).